# File to be moved based on numeric value in name

Tags: excel, vba, file, numeric

hi all I am trying to make a macro to move a selection of files from a parent folder into a sub folder in the same location example being - C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Mail Merge\Headersheets being parent folder and sub folder being -C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Mail Merge\Headersheets\moved. in the moved folder there is also a list of folders based on the files made and are all numeric - based on the document they are for. the documents are made first using a mail merge process that is fine but needing to first identify the case ID in the file example  - C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Mail Merge\Headersheets\headersheet 123456.Docm and have this moved into the following folder - C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Mail Merge\Headersheets\moved\123456. the following code has worked if the folder is named the same as the Document but this would still require each folder being renamed. can anybody please help ? here is the full code I have so far I think I need to use a split but cant figure it out

```
Public Sub Move_Files_To_Matching_Folder()

Dim sourceFolder As String, destMainFolder As String, destSubfolder As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim folderPath As String
Dim FSfile As Object
Dim FSsourceFolder As Object
Dim FoldPathPrompt As FileDialog

Set FoldPathPrompt = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FoldPathPrompt
        .Title = "Select the folder you want to organise files in"
            'If OK is selected, assign the folder path to the FolderPath variable
                If .Show = -1 Then sourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With
folderPath = sourceFolder

    'If a folder path has been specified...
   If folderPath <> "" Then

sourceFolder = folderPath   'Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Desktop\test\"
destMainFolder = folderPath & "\moved\" 'Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Desktop\test\moved\"
If Dir(destMainFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir (destMainFolder)
    End If
    
If Right(sourceFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sourceFolder = sourceFolder & "\"
If Right(destMainFolder, 1) <> "\" Then destMainFolder = destMainFolder & "\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FSsourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sourceFolder)
For Each FSfile In FSsourceFolder.Files
    destSubfolder = destMainFolder & Right(FSfile.Name, InStrRev(FSfile.Name, ".") - 1) '& "\"
    If FSO.FolderExists(destSubfolder) Then
        If FSO.FileExists(destSubfolder & FSfile.Name) Then FSO.DeleteFile destSubfolder & FSfile.Name, True
        FSfile.Move destSubfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but should get you most of the way there...

```vb
Public Sub Move_Files_To_Matching_Folder()

    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim FSO As Object, movedFolder As Object, FSsourceFolder As Object
    Dim folderPath As String, FSfile As Object, p, numPart As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder you want to organise files in"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSsourceFolder = FSO.getfolder(sourceFolder)
    Set movedFolder = CheckFolder(FSO.buildpath(sourceFolder, "moved"))
   
    For Each FSfile In FSsourceFolder.Files
        numPart = NumericPart(FSfile.Name)
        If Len(numPart) > 0 Then 'or some other threshold...
            p = FSO.buildpath(movedFolder.Path, numPart)
            CheckFolder p
            FSfile.Move p
        End If
    Next FSfile
End Sub

'get/create folder (parent path must exist!)
Function CheckFolder(fPath) As Object
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .folderexists(fPath) Then .createfolder fPath
        Set CheckFolder = .getfolder(fPath)
    End With
End Function

'get the first numeric portion of a string
Function NumericPart(fName) As String
    Dim i As Long, rv, ch
    For i = 1 To Len(fName)
        ch = Mid(fName, i, 1)
        If ch Like "#" Then
            rv = rv & ch 'add this digit
        Else
            If Len(rv) > 0 Then Exit For 'exit if no more digits
        End If
    Next i
    NumericPart = rv
End Function
```

Comment: this has gave some help with what I am after, but its only making the folders and not moving them to where they need to be. I might have a way of sorting it thanks